Android TV Emulator in Portrait Mode
I am developing a Flutter app which will run on Tvs. However, these tvs are in portrait mode and I want to test my app in TV emulator but in portrait mode. I couldn't find any way to change tv orientation landscape to portrait. Is there any way to do this? Thank you.
